# Adding a number to old IDs via dynamic htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a number (1000) to the backreferenced (old) IDs with a dynamic rewrite rule, for URLs that look like this:

```
 /en/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-123.html
 /en/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-3.html
 /en/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-12.html
```

What i need is this:

```
 /en/item/1123
 /en/item/1003
 /en/item/1012
```

My try looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^/en/(.*)-_-([0-9]+)\.html$ /en/item/1$2 [R=301,L]
```

But that way it only works for old IDs which have three digits.

Comment: Your try doesn't seem to attempt to include `.html` on the end of the destination URL. Just write 3 rewrite rules, one for each 1-digit, 2-digit and 3-digit.

Comment: I corrected the question. But will 3 rewrite rules also work if there is only one digit? Like in line 2?

Comment: Sure, because one of those three rules you write will match that case specifically.

Comment: You are right. This was easier I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # /en/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-123.html to /en/item/1123
    RewriteRule ^en\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)-_-([0-9]{3})\.html$ /en/item/1$4 [R=301,L]

    # /en/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-3.html to /en/item/1003
    RewriteRule ^en\/(.*)\/(.*)-_-([0-9]{1})\.html$ /en/item/100$3 [R=301,L]

    # /en/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx-_-12.html to /en/item/1012
    RewriteRule ^en\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)-_-([0-9]{2})\.html$ /en/item/10$5 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```